# How to attach a struct to the main ViewController?

Tags: vstack, hstack

**How to attach a struct to the main GameViewController?**

This **struct** occupies the top half of the main **ViewController**.

The goal is to have this **struct** be part of the **main** `GameViewController` and **not** in  **separate** `UIHostingController`.

SO, when I rotate the main SKScene for example the **struct** also rotates OR when I switch SKScenes both the top-half struct and the bottom-half switch **together** because they are one SKScene.

The programmer who invented `HStacks` and `VStacks` is a blooming genius … but I need to avoid what I have now which is the `HStack` `VStack` combo closing and then its neighbors in the main SKScene closing.

Here are the essential code segments - all in my `GameViewController`:

Declared at the top:

```
var useGSO = true
var gsoChildVC: UIViewController!   // = UIHostingController

override func viewDidLoad() {

    showScene()

    /*
        "gso" = "Game Static Objects"
    */
    if useGSO {
        // create a UIHostingController and extract a rootView for later processing
        gsoChildVC = UIHostingController(rootView: GameStaticObjects())
    }
    
}   // viewDidLoad
```

Within my `showScene()`:

```
func addGamePieces(toScene: SKScene) {
    
    if thisSceneName == "GameScene" {

        // various SKSpriteNodes

        //
        // STATIC People, Animals and Buildings
        // are now added to the top of our SKScene
        //
        addGSOChild(toScene: toScene)

    }   // if thisSceneName == "GameScene"
    else {
        
        removeGSOChild()
        
    }
                
}   // addGamePieces


func addGSOChild(toScene: SKScene) {
    
    // gsoChildVC = nil *if* useGSO = false
    guard gsoChildVC == nil else {
        let gsoParentVC = self  // parent = us = GameViewController
        
        // default value
    //  gsoChildVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        
        /**/
        let sameWidth = gsoParentVC.view.bounds.width
        let newHeight = 0.5 * gsoParentVC.view.bounds.height
        let boundsWithNewBottom = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, sameWidth, newHeight)
        gsoChildVC.view.frame = boundsWithNewBottom
        /**/
        
        // first, add the view of the child to the view of the parent
        gsoParentVC.view.addSubview(gsoChildVC.view)
        // then, add the child to the parent
        gsoParentVC.addChild(gsoChildVC)
        
        // notify the child ViewController that we're finished
        gsoChildVC.didMove(toParent: gsoParentVC)
        
        return
    }

}   // addGSOChild


func removeGSOChild() {
  
    // gsoChildVC = nil *if* useGSO = false
    guard gsoChildVC == nil else {
        // First, remove the Child from its Parent
        gsoChildVC.removeFromParent()
        
        // Then, remove the Child's view from the Parent's
        gsoChildVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        
        return
    }
    
}   // removeGSOChild
```

As stated at the top of this OP, the `HStack` and `Stack` code appears great .. but the `UIHostingController` is distinct from my `GameViewController`. As a direct result, such operations as switching `SKScene`s is done in 2 halves - (1) the `HStack` and `Stack` top half and (2) whatever  **non-**`struct` stuff appears below it.

If I switch `SKScenes`, I want both halves to switch **as one entity**.

FWIW, the `struct` that contains the `HStack` and `Stack` code is **outside** the `GameViewController` **class** as suggested by Apple.

**and** as specified above, I call:

`gsoChildVC = UIHostingController(rootView: GameStaticObjects())`

within my `viewDidLoad()` method.

I would love some basic guidance here as to what basic error I am making.